How to solve the Error ”Cannot find package '/progress-rate-calculator/node_modules/casperjs/' imported from /progress-rate-calculator/calculate.js”
I've been creating web scraping slack bot.
When I installed casperjs on yarn, then I ran the program below, I got the error below, that can't find package "casperjs" imported from calculate.js. How can I fix it? My project's package manager is yarn.
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package '/progress-rate-calculator/node_modules/casperjs/' imported from /progress-rate-calculator/calculate.js
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
    at legacyMainResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:235:9)
    at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:876:14)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:938:20)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1153:11)
    at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:838:30)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:424:18)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:77:40)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}

calculate.js:
"use strict";
import bolt from "@slack/bolt";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import chalk from "chalk";
import casperjs from "casperjs";
const casper = casperjs.create();
dotenv.config();
console.log(`SLACK_APP_TOKEN: ${process.env.SLACK_APP_TOKEN}`);
console.log(`SLACK_BOT_TOKEN: ${process.env.SLACK_BOT_TOKEN}`);
const app = new bolt.App({
    token: process.env.SLACK_BOT_TOKEN,
    appToken: process.env.SLACK_APP_TOKEN,
    socketMode: true,
    logLevel: "debug"
});

casper.start();

const urls = {
  "MathA": [
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1919/chapters/26869",
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1919/chapters/26870",
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1919/chapters/26871",
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1919/chapters/26872",
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1919/chapters/26873",
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1919/chapters/26874",
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1919/chapters/26875",
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1919/chapters/26876"
  ],
  "History": [
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1859/chapters/24327",
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1859/chapters/24328",
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1859/chapters/24329",
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1859/chapters/24330",
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1859/chapters/24331",
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1859/chapters/24332",
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1859/chapters/24333",
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1859/chapters/24334",
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1859/chapters/24335"
   ],
  "Home Economics": [
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1919/chapters/26869",
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1919/chapters/26870",
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1919/chapters/26871",
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1919/chapters/26872",
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1919/chapters/26873",
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1919/chapters/26874",
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1919/chapters/26875",
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1919/chapters/26876",
  ],
  "Japanese": [
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1847/chapters/24267",
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1847/chapters/24268",
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1847/chapters/24269",
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1847/chapters/24270",
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1847/chapters/24271",
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1847/chapters/24272",
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1847/chapters/24273",
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1847/chapters/24274",
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1847/chapters/24275",
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1847/chapters/24276",
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1847/chapters/24277",
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1847/chapters/24278"
  ],
  "art": [
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1903/chapters/24092",
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1903/chapters/24093",
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1903/chapters/24094",
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1903/chapters/24095",
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1903/chapters/24096",
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1903/chapters/24097",
  ],
  "health": [
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1901/chapters/24080",
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1901/chapters/24081",
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1901/chapters/24082",
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1901/chapters/24083",
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1901/chapters/24084",
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1901/chapters/24085",
  ],
  "biology": [
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1889/chapters/24357",
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1889/chapters/24358",
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1889/chapters/24359",
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1889/chapters/24360",
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1889/chapters/24361",
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1889/chapters/24362",
  ],
  "English": [
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1911/chapters/24146",
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1911/chapters/24147",
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1911/chapters/24148",
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1911/chapters/24149",
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1911/chapters/24150",
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1911/chapters/24151",
  ],
  "Physical Education": [
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1897/chapters/24170",
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1897/chapters/24171",
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/1897/chapters/24172",
  ],
  "Spacial Activity": [
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/2025/chapters/25318",
    "https://www.nnn.ed.nico/courses/2024/chapters/25317"
  ]
}
const percentages = [];

const login_id = process.env.LOGIN_ID;
const password = process.env.PASSWORD;

app.message(/pro-rate (.+)/i, async({message, say}) => {
  const argument = message.text.match(/pro-rate (.+)/i)[0];
  console.log(chalk.green(argument));
  console.log(chalk.blue("First value of the retrieved category:", urls.argument[argument][0]));
  casper.start("https://www.nnn.ed.nico/oauth_login?next_url=https://www.nnn.ed.nico/home&target_type=n_high_school_mypage", function(){
    this.fillSelectors("form#oauth_identifier", { 
      'input[name="loginId"]': login_id,
      'input[name="password"]': password
    }, true);
  });
  casper.waitForUrl("https://www.nnn.ed.nico/home", function(){
    for(let i = 0; i <= urls[argument].length; i++){
      this.thenOpen(urls[argument][i], function() {
         const progressRate = document.querySelector("li.sc-1yme7mc-3.eZrrkf").slice(3, 6).value;
         console.log(chalk.blue("Progress Rate:", progressRate));
         if(progressRate === "100") {
          percentages.push(Number(progressRate));
         }
         percentages.push(Number(progressRate.slice(2, 3)));
      });
    }
  });
  
  casper.run();

  let sum = 0;

   percentages.forEach((value) => { sum += value });
   say(`Current progress rate: ${sum / urls[argument].length}%`);
});

app.start();

"dependencies" part in package.json:
  "dependencies": {
    "@slack/bolt": "^3.17.1",
    "@types/phantomjs": "^1.9.35",
    "casperjs": "^1.1.4",
    "chalk": "^5.3.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5"
  },

I already tried:

Install casperjs with Typescript type definition like "@types/casperjs"
import the casperjs with the code "import casperjs from "@types/casperjs";"
change way to import with the code "const casperjs = requrie("casperjs");" instead of import (but this returned an error "ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead")

